# When to use Navigation vs 'State based switching' between components and pages in a React application?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm new to React.

In React, we use navigation with a library like... 'react-router-dom' to navigate to pages. My question is most of the time, I can show and hide the entire Component based on the item selected in a navigation bar. I can store a value in the state and if the selection changes, I can show another component. **Then why should we use a navigation library to navigate around?**

I can not find any clear information about this online. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

I was writing in this answer about having a more organized code (easier to maintenance) and a better folder structure, but you could easily have it working without a navigation library.

Probably the main point to use a navigation library is, as said in [React Router page](https://reactrouter.com/), whether you want to have bookmarkable URLs for your web app or a composable way to navigate in React Native.

**Web**

The library will help you work with the URL, receive parameters, navigate between pages.

**Mobile**

You can make use of [deep linking](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/), receive parameters, navigate between screens, animations, components ready for [Stack navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/), [Drawer navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation/), [Bottom Tab navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation/)...

---

You can do anything I mentioned above by yourself, but libraries exist because other people had a need and you decide to use it if you have the same need and think it's worth it.

> Why should we use a navigation library to navigate around?

In short, because they are widely used, well-tested libraries, with a performance that you may not be able to achieve easily if you want to have many different functionalities like those libraries have. And they will certainly save you a lot of time in case you need to create a way to navigate and work with things related to navigation (like those mentioned about Web and Mobile).

If your project is simple, there is no need to use a navigation library. To have a more practical experience, you can even try to do your project without using such a library, and when you are having difficulties, try replacing your logic with some library and analyze if it was worth it.